# Polymer 2.x code works in jsbin but not in codepen, plunker or jsfiddle

Tags: polymer, jsfiddle, plunker, jsbin, codepen

The below code works properly in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zocoyomumo/1/edit?html,console,output) but it does not work in either [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzrdWd), [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/c6De8Fbl9CUvRP1J0iS0?p=preview) or [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmw6L7h8/).

Why not? How can I get it to work in the three locations where it does not?

http://jsbin.com/yudavucola/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">

  <!-- Ensure Web Animations polyfill is loaded since neon-animation 2.0 doesn't import it -->
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/web-animations.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/animations/scale-up-animation.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/animations/fade-out-animation.html">

</head>
<body>
  <dom-module id="my-el">
    <template>
      <button on-click="open">Open Dialog</button>
      <paper-dialog
        id="dialog"
        entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
        exit-animation="fade-out-animation"
        modal
       >
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <div>Dialog body</div>
      </paper-dialog>
    </template>
    <script>
      class MyEl extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'my-el' }

    constructor() {
      super();
        }

        open() {
          console.log('opening...');
          this.$.dialog.open();
          console.log('opened!');
        }

      }

      customElements.define(MyEl.is, MyEl);
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <my-el></my-el>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every other site other than **jsbin** is using the secure version of `HTTP` i.e. `HTTPS`, the request to get the contents from the source `http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/` is blocked. So, use secure connection and it will work in every other site.

You can check the console for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<base>` tag's `href` attribute from `http://polygit.org/...` to `//polygit.org/...`. This normalizes the import to work in both `http` and `https` environments.

Here are working examples in all repositories: [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/nakikoqemu/1/edit?html,console,output), [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeOxgZ), [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hPCb4EUMVX9zWW9iEuq0?p=preview) and [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwvdtpg8/1/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <base href="//polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">

  <!-- Ensure Web Animations polyfill is loaded since neon-animation 2.0 doesn't import it -->
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/web-animations.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/animations/scale-up-animation.html">
  <link rel="import" href="neon-animation/animations/fade-out-animation.html">

</head>
<body>
  <dom-module id="my-el">
    <template>
      <button on-click="open">Open Dialog</button>
      <paper-dialog
        id="dialog"
        entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
        exit-animation="fade-out-animation"
        modal
       >
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <div>Dialog body</div>
      </paper-dialog>
    </template>
    <script>
      class MyEl extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'my-el' }

    constructor() {
      super();
        }

        open() {
          console.log('opening...');
          this.$.dialog.open();
          console.log('opened!');
        }

      }

      customElements.define(MyEl.is, MyEl);
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <my-el></my-el>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit

Note that for a specific version of Polymer, you can use

```
<base href="//polygit.org/polymer2.0+:master/components/">
```

or

```
<base href="//polygit.org/polymer1.0+:master/components/">
```

etc.